# Очистка кэша apt-get

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu

Как правильно удалить закачанные архивы пакетов apt-get? Я посмотрел в папку

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

и нашел там список пакетов `*.deb`, можно их просто удалить, но непонятно, правильно ли это.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для очистки локального кэша пакетов используется apt-get с командой clean:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Подробнее - в *man apt-get*.

Answer (score 1):

В процессе установки через APT в каталоге /var/cache/apt/archives кэшируются файлы пакетов, и их можно удалить.

```
 # apt-get autoclean # удаляет только неиспользованные файлы пакетов
 # apt-get clean     # удаляет все файлы из кэша
```